# Power bank with step up converter

Tags: power

I have attached a step up converter with 3.7V mobile battery and also attached a lithium Ion battery in parallel and for recharging both batteries I have attached a power bank circuit. I have attached step up converter to run a 12V light and through power bank circuit I can also charge my phone.

Is this type of thing that I made safe?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nothing you have said gives me confidence that you won’t be mangling the batteries withe ill conceived currents from the power bank hence, it cannot be judged to be safe.

Comment: Before you start using this platform, please go through the basic safety guidelines of this field! Your circuit is disturbingly dangerous and I hope this question gets closed down due to you having no regard for safety!

Comment: It **MAY** be 'sort of safe' despite what the nay sayers say. | Your construction methods LOOK somewhat rough BUT it is possible to build things the way you have and still have them done technically well. USUALLY rough construction indicates poor safety BUT this is not always true. | What we need is a connection diagram / circuit diagram, as what you have done is not fully clear from your description - and complete clarity is needed for our input to be useful. | PLEASE provide a connection diagram with enough detail for us to understand exactly what you are doing.